# bash recursive function for counting files

Tags: bash, shell

So I wanted to make a shell script that counts all hidden files, aliases and subdirectories in a folder. Problem is that it the recursive call of the function I created doesn't go beyond the first depth level:

```
function recursive_func()
{
    current=$1
    echo $current
    for thing in $(ls -A $current)
    do
        if [ -d $current/$thing ]
        then
            let subd++
            recursive_func $current/$thing
        elif [ -L $thing ] ; then
            let symlinks++
        elif [ -f $thing -a ${thing:0:1} == "." ] ; then
            let hidden++
        fi
    done
}
```

However, one of my colleague managed to do it and it looks like this:

```
function recursive_func()
{
    echo $1
    for thing in $(ls -A $1)
    do
        path=$1/$thing
        if [ -d $path ]
        then
            let subd++
            recursive_func $path
        elif [ -L $path ] ; then
            let symlinks++
        elif [ -f $path-a ${thing:0:1} == "." ]; then
            let hidden++
        fi
    done
}
```

I can't tell why the second version works but mine doesn't. Any help?

Edit:
The problem was that `current` was global and so after every recursive call the value was wrong for the rest of the iterations in the `for` loop. Fixed it by adding `local` in front of `current`, or by just using `$1` instead.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Looks like the most important difference is `path=$1/$thing` and checking `$path` instead of `$thing`. But in order to help you more, you need to be specific about what "doesn't work" means. Do you get errors, are your counts all `0`, or what?

Comment: I have a restriciton to not use `find` or `ls -R`.

Comment: Since you're using Bash, this is the best approach in my opinion https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1174/67817.

Comment: Do you traverse symlinks to directories?

Comment: No, I don't traverse symlinks to directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current` is a global variable and after every recursive call the value is wrong for the rest of the iterations in the for loop. Fixed it by adding local in front of current, or by just using $1 instead.

```
function recursive_func()
{
    local current=$1
    echo $current
    for thing in $(ls -A $current)
    do
        if [ -d $current/$thing ]
        then
            let subd++
            recursive_func $current/$thing
        elif [ -L $thing ] ; then
            let symlinks++
        elif [ -f $thing -a ${thing:0:1} == "." ] ; then
            let hidden++
        fi
    done
}
```

or

```
function recursive_func()
{
    echo $1
    for thing in $(ls -A $1)
    do
        if [ -d $1/$thing ]
        then
            let subd++
            recursive_func $1/$thing
        elif [ -L $1/$thing ] ; then
            let symlinks++
        elif [ -f $1/$thing -a ${thing:0:1} == "." ] ; then
            let hidden++
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use find to avoid the recursive call and count the output lines with wc -l.

Try this in the folder to search:

```
find -mindepth 1 -name '.*'
find -mindepth 1 -name '.*' | wc -l
```

Comment: I have a restriciton to not use `find` or `ls -R`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
recursive_func () {
    shopt -s dotglob
    for item in $1/*; {
        fname=$(basename $item)
        [[ -L $item ]] && ((symlinks++))
        [[ ${fname::1} = '.' ]] && ((hidden++))
        [[ -d $item ]] && { ((subd++)); recursive_func "$item"; }
    }
    shopt -u dotglob
}
```

Comment: Oh, my bad, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -al | wc -l
```

The first command lists all files in the directory, and puts them in the long format, so that they occupy one line each.  The second command counts the lines.

Apologies; I just realised you wanted recursion.